# Solutions for Project

Tags: asp.net

I hope you guys could help me come up with a new solution for a customer. The scope of the project detailed getting data from me. So I created a user interface where the user could select the data they wanted and I would create an xml file that automatically sent it to the user through email. I limited the user to only be able to select 5 items at a time so that the tool would not time out b/c there is a lot of data in the xml that needs to be generated based on the selection. Now the user is asking not to be limited to 5 and wants to be able to select how many he/she desires. My question is are there any other solutions to handle this problem.

Comment: How about starting the execution / generation of the data asynchronous? (e.g. just start the execution in another thread).

Comment: 5 sounds few. Try putting a greater limit, like 100, 500, etc. Other option is to use a sort of pagination, sending several mails to the customer. Another one is to process the whole query in background and send the email when it's done, but not blocking the UI.

Comment: 5 items, 10000 items is not a lot of data. Why are you concerned with timeouts?

Comment: @Icarus well 5 items can maybe generate a lot of data. maybe evaluate 5 different log files (or tables) or something alike. ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding. The reason why I limit it to 5 is b/c I first limited it to 10 and it timed out b/c its so much data.

Comment: For example, say I let them select city and they choose Chicago. In the xml it would give the population, highways, streets, etc... you can see how much data it could be along with calculations and things of that nature, plus you have to pull all that data from different tables in the database. What im trying to get across is that it takes time to get information and then build xml from that, and finding that if you could to many item, the website time out

Comment: And lets take it one step further with my example above let say I let them choose state instead of cities and they choose California. See how much data we could be talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

one little hack to reuse your current solution would be to write a wrapper so as to accept any number of items as selection, then process them by chunks of 5 ( or whichever limit you choose)